# feathersjs sockets using events

Tags: javascript, sockets, dom-events, feathersjs

In the feathersjs docs, e.g. [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/socketio.html#find), recommended way to call the server is by emitting an event. Why not just directly make the app call? So why use:

```
socket.emit('find', 'messages', { status: 'read', user: 10 }, (error, data) => {
  console.log('Found all messages', data);
});
```

When you can simply do:

```
app.service('messages').find({ query: { status: 'read', user: 10 } })
```

Is this just people preferring the event notation or are there other arguments to consider?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation page you linked explains how to use the websocket directly - for example if you connect with an Android app or don't want to/can't use Feathers on the client.

It **is recommended** to use Feathers on the client whenever possible and it does the exact same thing for you automatically under the hood. A client code like this:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
const socketio = require('@feathersjs/socketio-client');

const socket = io('http://api.my-feathers-server.com');
const app = feathers().configure(socketio(socket));

app.service('messages').find({ query: { status: 'read', user: 10 } })
  .then(data => console.log('Found all messages', data));
```

Does the exact same thing as

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io('http://api.my-feathers-server.com');

socket.emit('find', 'messages', { status: 'read', user: 10 }, (error, data) => {
  console.log('Found all messages', data);
});
```

But with the first you get the goodness (hooks, events, promises, authentication) and familiarity of a Feathers app.